# Place pin randomly on road - iOS Maps Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm trying to figure out how I can place an annotation randomly on a road.
I can randomly position an annotation onto a map, but I would like this annotation to be on a road and not in a shopping mall/building/home etc.

Does anyone know the best way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy would be to take your random coordinate and then reverse geocode it. That will provide an address closest to your random coordinate. Once reverse geocoded, you can use the result of that process to create your annotation.